How to show that this space has same homotopy type as the classifying space of infinite unitary group
To show space $\bigcup_{n\geq 1} \frac{U_{2n}}{U_{n}\times U_{n}}$ has the same homotopy type as $BU = \bigcup_{k\geq 1}BU(k)$, where $BU(k)=\bigcup_{n\geq k} \frac{U_{n}}{U_{k}\times U_{n-k}}$ and $U_{n}$ is the $n\times n$ unitary matrices.
I tried looking into the inclusion map to show it is a weak equivalence, couldn't get anywhere with that.

This question appeared , while proving Bott Periodicity Theorem (from Switzer), instead of taking the usual definition, they instead work with this space , with the same homotopy type.

The "union" here is of course a direct limit. The space $BU$ is the direct limit of $U_n/(U_k\times U_{n-k})$ for all $k\le n$, by construction. You have to properly write down the transition maps and then you should see that the spaces $U_{2n}/(U_n\times U_n)$ are cofinal in this direct limit.
